# NDSolve unable to solve system of PDEs

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm trying to solve a set of PDEs and am running into problems. The system is defined by:
[image: System of PDEs]

As can be seen, there are two dynamical equations for $\rho$ and $\phi$, but the equation for $v$ has no time derivative on it. I take Dirichlet boundary conditions for all variables, $\rho(x=-L) = \rho(x=L) = \rho_0$, $\phi(x=-L) = 1, \phi(x=L) = 0$ and $V(x=-L)=v(x=L)=0$. Initial conditions are $\rho(x, t=0)= \rho_0$, $\phi(x, t=0)$ is a sigmoid function going from 1 to 0 and $V(x, t=0)=0$.

Somehow, `NDSolve` is unable to solve this system under certain conditions. In that case, when I run `NDSolve` it seems to generate an infinite loop and never terminates, while using up a lot of CPU/memory on my PC.

For reference, here is the current working code thanks to @Alex Trounev (sorry for the poor formatting):

```
kA := 1/τ ((ρdA - ρ[x, t])/ρdA);
kB := 1/τ ((ρdB - ρ[x, t])/ρdB); 
e := (eM (1 - ϕ[x, t]) + eO ϕ[x, t]) ; 
kD := α e; params = {ρdA -> 0.3, ρdB -> 
   1, ρh -> 1, τ -> 0.5, 
  D1 -> 0.01, η -> 0.1, ξ -> 0.1, kF -> 1, z -> 1, 
  e0 -> 1, α -> 0, eM -> 1, eO -> 1, 
  fc -> 0, χ -> 1, κ -> 
   1}; tmax = 1; L = 1; iv = {ρ[x, 
     0] == (Tanh[8 x] + 1)/2 (ρdA - ρdB) + ρdB, ϕ[
     x, 0] == (1 - Tanh[8 x])/2, v[x, 0] == 0} /. 
  params; bc = {ρ[-L, 
     t] == (Tanh[-8 L] + 1)/
       2 (ρdA - ρdB) + ρdB, ρ[L, 
     t] == (Tanh[8 L] + 1)/
       2 (ρdA - ρdB) + ρdB, ϕ[-L, 
     t] == (1 + Tanh[8 L])/2, ϕ[L, t] == (1 - Tanh[8 L])/2, 
   v[-L, t] == 0, v[L, t] == 0} /. params;
PDEsys = {D[ρ[x, t], t] + 
     D[ρ[x, t] (v[x, t]), 
      x] == (kA (1 - ϕ[x, t]) + kB ϕ[x, t]) ρ[x, t], 
   D[ϕ[x, t], t] + (v[x, t]) D[ϕ[x, t], x] == 
    D1 D [ϕ[x, t], {x, 2}] + 
     z D1 D[ρ[x, t], 
       x] D[ϕ[x, t], x]/ρ[x, t] + (kB - kA + kF) ϕ[x, 
       t] (1 - ϕ[x, t]) + 
     kD (1 - ϕ[x, t]), η D[v[x, t], {x, 2}] - ξ v[x, 
       t] == e D[ρ[x, t], x]/ρ[x, t] + 
     D[e, x] Log[ρ[x, t]/ρh]};
vars = {ρ, ϕ, v}
fullsys = Simplify@Join[PDEsys /. params, bc, iv];
ndsol = NDSolve[fullsys, vars, {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
    "IndexReduction" -> Automatic}]
```

Now I'm simplifying a few conditions, and the question is how to get it working when `eM` is not equal to `eO`, and when `alpha` is not equal to zero.

Comment: When you say "unable to solve the system", what exactly do you receive back? A solution that you believe is incorrect? An error, and if so, which error?

Comment: When I run `NDSolve` it seems to generate an infinite loop and never terminates, while using up a lot of CPU/memory on my PC.

Comment: It also generates a warning "NDSolve::pdord" with "Some of the functions have zero differential order, so the equations will be solved as a system of differential-algebraic equations"

Comment: You did not specify "params" and "bcDiriclet" and "iv "

Comment: Yeah no, I'm not copying my complete script, but I'll include these as well

Comment: @PianoEntropy If you don't provide complete code and definitions, then we cannot run the code. If we cannot run the code, then we can't help you. I am not sure how you imagine we could help otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean that I'm not sharing code, just not the whole script because most of it is irrelevant to the question and also unpublished. But I already included the relevant parts you mentioned so anyone should be able to reproduce the error if there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are exist range of parameters where `NDSolve` getting solution, for example,

```
params = {kA -> .1, kB -> 1, D1 -> .1, \[Eta] -> 1, \[Xi] -> 1, 
  kD -> 1, kF -> .5, 
  z -> 1}; rh0 = 1; tmax = 1; L = 1; iv = {\[Rho][x, 0] == 
   rh0, \[Phi][x, 0] == (1 - Tanh[8 x])/2, 
  v[x, 0] == 0}; bc = {\[Rho][-L, t] == rh0, \[Rho][L, t] == 
   rh0, \[Phi][-L, t] == (1 + Tanh[8 L])/2, \[Phi][L, 
    t] == (1 - Tanh[8 L])/2, v[-L, t] == 0, v[L, t] == 0};

PDEsys = {D[\[Rho][x, t], t] + 
     D[\[Rho][x, t] (v[x, t]), 
      x] == (kA (1 - \[Phi][x, t]) + kB \[Phi][x, t]) \[Rho][x, t], 
   D[\[Phi][x, t], t] + (v[x, t]) D[\[Phi][x, t], x] == 
    D1 D[\[Phi][x, t], {x, 2}] + 
     z D1 D[\[Rho][x, t], 
       x] D[\[Phi][x, t], x]/\[Rho][x, t] + (kB - kA + kF) \[Phi][x, 
       t] (1 - \[Phi][x, t]) + 
     kD, \[Eta] D[v[x, t], {x, 2}] - \[Xi] v[x, t] == 
    D[\[Rho][x, t], x]/\[Rho][x, t]};
vars = {\[Rho], \[Phi], v}
fullsys = Join[PDEsys /. params, bc, iv];

ndsol = NDSolve[fullsys, vars, {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
    "IndexReduction" -> Automatic}]
```

Visualization

```
{Plot3D[\[Rho][x, t] /. ndsol[[1]], {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
  Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> "\[Rho]"], 
 Plot3D[\[Phi][x, t] /. ndsol[[1]], {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
  Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> "\[Phi]"], 
 Plot3D[v[x, t] /. ndsol[[1]], {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, Mesh -> None,
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> "v"]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Very interesting! It seems that with a smaller choice for tmax and L this gives the right results. It still puzzles me why one needs specific parameters and not everything works. But this already helps a lot, thanks!

Comment: There  is  region of stability for numerical method. Actually parameters $L=1; tmax=1$ are not small, but about unit. For some numerical methods it is optimal combination. In this example we use DAE solver.

Comment: If you have a little more time, here's another question: if I replace the third PDE by `\[Eta] D[v[x, t], {x, 2}] - \[Xi] v[x, t] ==  e  D[\[Rho][x, t], x]/\[Rho][x, t]`, and define `e:=(eM (1 - \[Phi][x, t]) + eO \[Phi][x, t])`, then it doesn't solve it anymore, and outputs "The DAE solver failed at t = 0. The solver is intended for index 1 \
DAE systems and structural analysis indicates that the DAE is \
structurally singular." Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @PianoEntropy Do you mean that `e=(eM (1 - \[Phi][x, t]) + eO \[Phi][x, t])=1` at `eM=1;eO=1;`?

Comment: If `eM=eO` then `e=0`, so we have to choose them to be different, e.g. `eM=0.8, eO=1`. Then just add a factor `eM (1 - \[Phi][x, t]) + eO \[Phi][x, t])` in front of the RHS expression of the third PDE.

Comment: I've updated the question with your working code. Now the question becomes how to get it working for `eM` not equal to `eO`, as well as `alpha>0`.

Comment: @PianoEntropy Do you mean that `e=(eM (1 - \[Phi][x, t]) + eO \[Phi][x, t])=eM` if `eM=eO`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, `e=eM` then. But `e` should in the end depend on `\[Phi][x,t]`, and this is when it gives a problem.

Comment: @PianoEntropy Use my code with 3rd equation in a form `\[Rho][x, 
   t] (\[Eta] D[v[x, t], {x, 2}] - \[Xi] v[x, t]) == (1 + kap \[Phi][x,
       t]) D[\[Rho][x, t], x]` with `-1<kap<1`.

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly, just moving the division by `\[Rho][x,t]` to the LHS of the third equation seems to get rid of the error message!